# Who to complain to about the speed of airport security at Frankfurt?

Tags: airports, germany, airport-security, fra

Usually I'm flying several times every month or two in Europe, and in the last few years I have seen that the situation at security check is worse and worse.

One week ago I had a flight via Frankfurt.  I had a connection for 1 hour and 10 minutes; my previous flight was late.  I had to run through the airport, and I was stopped at the security check.

There were only two 'doors', one for economy, the other for business and first class. Flying in economy but having short connection, I went to the business class queue.  After about 15 minutes in the line I finally got to the control (if I went to economy I suppose it would have been an hour).

There I saw a lot of agents walking around, laughing, speaking to each other, etc.  They really don't care that a lot of people can miss their flights.  I told one of them that it's not ok.  I got the response that if I didn't like something I could call the police.  I didn't have time for it as my connection was really short.  I ran to my gate and I missed my flight.

After my flight left without me, I had some other problems and forgot about this situation.  But for the next time, those security agents, who are they? Airport staff? I don't think that it's police or that they have any relation to the police.

Does somebody know where can I make a complaint next time?

**Update 17/12/2017**: I'd like to say thank you for all answers and comments, it gives useful experience. Just a small detail: after I missed my flight I spent two days in Frankfurt until I could get another one. That's why I'm so unhappy

Comment: Not really a question for here, but I would ask the airport about that particular incident.

Comment: My recollection from Frankfurt is that the security screeners *are* police, or at least government agents of some sort, but it's been a while since I've been there so I may be wrong or the situation may have changed.

Comment: How dare anybody in a service position have fun while working! Especially when they're meant to be operating a queue... well, you know for a fact that *they were* meant to be operating a queue, and not monitoring customers or observing other staff or on a short break, right?

Comment: Your only angle is to complain to the airport that it takes too long to pass through security. The airport will check what is happening (how long it takes, how many people are passing through) and see if it is within the limits defined in the contract.  If it is within limits, it will not matter how many workers were not servicing you. And I bet that they already monitor that data on their own, but you can complain to it if it makes you happy. Remember, you are the airport's customer, you are neither the security company's customer nor its boss.

Comment: `They really don't care that a lot of people *who arrive late* miss their flights.`  FTFY. It is you who has to arrive at security with enough time to clear it; the fact that you are in a hurry(even if it is not your fault) does not mean anything to the security people (there is always someone who is late, and hey, they do not even know). You could *nicely ask* them for some help since it is a bad situation for you, but you are not anybody's boss to tell what they should or should not be doing.

Comment: Blame the terrorists and those who make the requirement for security a problem. You'd be complaining too if security was quick, but they missed something.

Comment: @SJuan76 The comment field is for asking for clarification. If you are answering the question, please use the _answer_ section so it can be vetted by the community.

Comment: @SJuan76 I agree that the late is my problem. That I don't like is that 2 gates opened from 10, no really fast lane... For example in Paris, Amsterdam there is a person who checks your boarding pass and allows you to go in fast lane. Nothing here at all

Comment: @djsmiley2k [I will](http://www.washingtonexaminer.com/tsa-missed-95-percent-of-weapons-explosives-in-security-tests/article/2565360) [take](http://abcnews.go.com/US/tsa-fails-tests-latest-undercover-operation-us-airports/story?id=51022188) [quick security](http://onemileatatime.boardingarea.com/2017/11/09/tsa-failure-rate/), [thank you very much](https://www.theatlantic.com/national/archive/2014/01/tsa-business-security-theater-not-security/357599/) [I'm more likely to be killed in car accident anyway].

Comment: Two days? I would have demanded to be put on another carrier well before then. It's not your fault you missed the flight, your inbound was late and I assume you had made reasonable provision for connections (I don't know what the recommended minimum time is in Frankfurt). Assuming you were booked on a through ticket, you should have been put on _any_ available flight by _any_ carrier to your destination, direct or indirect, if they had a spare seat. The only way I don't see this being possible is if the airport was closed or there were zero spare seats or no-shows (which seems very unlikely).

Comment: @Crazymoomin It was not possible due to weather, I was rebooked 3 times but all 3 filghts were canceled

Comment: @Vitalii ah right, yeah I heard about that one. Another option would possibly have been to take a train to another (open) German airport and fly from there, you can speak to customer services and mention the idea. By the sounds of it, you weren't the only one stranded for days, so I think your experience was atypical, under normal weather your delay would have not been so long.

Comment: You don't mention the details of your connecting flight.  If you were connected through the same ticket and airline then the airline should take care of you in the case of their flight being late and causing you to miss your connection.  If you were connected on separate tickets then the responsibility and risk is entirely your own.  Flights get delayed all the time.  Security queues take time.  If you're connecting on separate tickets you need to either take the risk of missing a flight and spending two days sorting out your next move **or** you book them with more time to connect.

Comment: @J... it was the same ticket, Lufthansa gave me two hotels, some food tickets, some emergency kit (this one I got second day only) with toothbrush and toothpaste, shave with cream, etc. 
Lufthansa was very good in this situation despite of the queues for several hours. But if security check was better I could probably get my flight

Comment: @Vitalii That's actually helpful information.  It sounds like, given the circumstances, they did as best as they could for you.  You can't really expect much more.  It's a risk of travel that sometimes this happens.  Next time the security check might be faster and you could still miss a connection if the plane is late enough.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

From [the Frankfurt airport website](https://www.frankfurt-airport.com/en/flights---more/transfer.detail.suffix.html/contact/general-contacts/all-contacts.html):

> The Federal Police will also deal with compliments and complaints concerning aviation security matters.
>
> Airport Security Check            +49 (0) 69 690 - 78578  bpold.frankfurt@polizei.bund.de

I believe much of the work is performed by contractors, but the police oversee the operation.

If you wish, the airport also has a general feedback address,   feedback@fraport.de, and it's possible they will take into account the complaints of dissatisfied passengers in their future planning.

Comment: So, they were actually right to suggest that OP "call the police". Not bad. +1

Comment: I would interpret this differently. "Concerning aviation security" is about anything that would endanger people or property. Someone missing their connecting flight really doesn't fall into that category.

Comment: @mrks but it says "**compliments** or complaints". The inclusion of compliments means it is about more than endangerment, and is talking about security issues as a whole. You can't call to compliment the fact that someone left a suspicious bag unattended or something, right? But you can compliment their protocols and whatnot, which i take to mean you can complain about those protocols as well.

Comment: Good point, that convinced me.

Answer (score 51):

Let me try to handle your implicit question, which I assume is "what can I do to prevent this next time?".

If you are in a line for security, and think there is a danger of you missing a flight, then the best way to deal with it is to talk to whoever is directing the lines. There is almost always someone, and if they agree that you might miss your flight they will often direct you to the front of the line. In fact if you think you are going to miss a flight, asking airport staff (or airline staff) for help as soon as possible is a good idea. Having passengers miss a flight is a problem for both airline and airport, and they will frequently make great efforts to get you to your gate on time if they know, and airlines are more likely to hold a flight a few minutes if they know you are on your way.

Waiting until you are at the head of the line and then telling the staff that their behaviour is bad is not going to help at all. As well as all the reasons o.m. said, the speed of a security line is usually limited by the number of bags that can be put through the machine. Having more people present, or having them being grim-faced (instead of laughing) or silent (instead of speaking) will not help at all.

Comment: I understand that if machine can accept 10 bags per minute we cannot put 11. But the problem was there there were at least 5 machines switched off.

Comment: Another point is to ask somebody in the front. I agree that it's a good point but unfortunately sometimes it does not work. I had 20 people from China, it was not very easy :)

Comment: And there was none who was directing the lines

Comment: For this answer, "whoever is directing the lines" could be extended to any staff on the scene that might help, e.g. the priority line for airport / airline staffs, which might take passengers in hurry at their discretion.

Comment: How about "ask the staff on your incoming (delayed) flight for assistance as soon as it becomes clear that you will be delayed with a strong possibility of missed connection"? Surprisingly, this often helps--they have a lot of options.

Comment: Been there, done that. Pisa, I think, small airport, Friday afternoon, taxi caught in traffic jam. Me, loudly, smiling "Help, people, my flight goes in 10 minutes, please let me through!" People "Of course, here, this way!" They even called ahead so the plane waited for me, as I ran up the steps the engines were running and they shut the door behind me.

Comment: @Vitalii don't assume that everyone physically there has the training and certification to legally operate the equipment not in use.

Comment: @RedSonja -- Then again, what Italian staff does to a RedSonja might not necessarily be what German staff would do to a Vitalii.

Comment: @Thomas We had the same at Tegel. If you are running late, skip the queue, go to the front. They even sometimes have a security guy "pre-sort" the queues because there is only so much space between security and gate. ("Passengers for Cologne, please stand back for now, passengers for Dusseldorf to the front of the queue.")

Answer (score 23):

While police will be present at the airport, actual checks may be done by contractors.

- The companies who provide security services are under pressure to keep costs low.
- These security contractors are usually not well paid, which does not increase their motivation or the competence of the available workers.
- That being said, they **are** entitled to rest breaks, etc. You have **no** idea when they went on shift, when they had scheduled breaks, and when they were supposed to go off shift.

Comment: While this addresses some of the OP’s questions it does not address the title question nor the last question: how to make a complaint.

Comment: I agree. One small addition: At least for Berlin, it is not about competence. To be allowed to work in airport security, you need training and a background check. Need to know about flight safety and law.

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt isn't that competence?

Comment: @user1997744, the OP wrote "But for the next time, those security agents, who are they?"

Comment: @o.m. Which is why I acknowledged you answered some of the OP’s questions but not the titular one.

Comment: @DonQuiKong The OP said, that due to bad payment the competence is low - I disagree :-) The basic knowledge you need to be allowed to work in aviation security is quite high imho. Non the less is bad payment a horrible basis for good work.

Answer (score 21):

From my experiences with airports and airlines, often the best way is the 'public' image. Emails can be ignored, phone calls diverted (not saying this is always the case), but social media managers seem to have their job description as getting 'angry' or 'bitter' or whatever negative opinions off twitter especially ASAP into private messages.

So for example, in this case I'd send a tweet out and mention [Airport_FRA](https://twitter.com/Airport_FRA) in it, and hashtag #frankfurtairport.  That way at least the mention might get passed on.

Comment: Very good point :)

Answer (score 7):

I don't remember the source but about a year ago I read an article written by airport staff and it included the answer to this question: "What to do if I'm short on time and need to pass through security to get to my connecting flight.". Basically the answer was that you need to go to the security staff (there's usually someone patrolling the queues or similar) and explain your situation. Do not go to the front of line and ask the people at the checkpoint. They're too busy.

As the airlines incurs a lot of loss from people needing to be rebooked due to missed flights, they are constantly pushing on the airport and its security staff to perform as efficiently as possible, and the security staff knows that the less people getting rebooked due to a missed connection, the better for them, so they will be eager to help you.

There's usually a semi-closed position or a VIP-position that they'll employ to service you right away. But you really need to be late yet still have a decent chance at making your connection for this to work so they will check your bording pass before doing anything and they still might refuse to help.

Answer (score 5):

```
"I had a connection for 1 hour and 10 minutes"
```

That is too short to make an international connection. I assume your connection was international because you said you  were stuck for two days before getting an alternate. Try claiming on your travel insurance, but they will probably not accept it. I suggest you complain to whom ever booked your ticket, you might get lucky.

Transfer guidelines and useful tips for Frankfurt Airport are published here: https://www.frankfurt-airport.com/en/flights---more/transfer.detail.suffix.html/article/flights-and-more/services-a-z/easy-travel/transfer-at-fra.html#fratransfer and it includes ensuring you have reasonable time to clear security which includes allowing for the fact an incoming flight can be late! From your description, Security were doing their job and operating within their published guidelines so it looks like there is no reasonable complaint you can make in this situation but if you do want to follow it up, security would be airport employees, so you can contact the airport authorities themselves in the first instance at feedback@fraport.de

Comment: I bought the ticket directly on Lufthansa's web site. The sell such connections. I've taken the same route at least three times and 1h was completely enough for transfer + passport control + security check. 
As for trevel insurance, I spoke with them and they could offer a hotel + taxi, that what lufthansa had offered.

Comment: A 1h connectin would never be accepted in the US though security.   It's barely acceptable for an airside connection.

Comment: @Vitalii - Now you know that a 1 hour connection is long enough. Three times out of four.

Comment: @PaulSmith If Lufthansa sells it that way, it's enough. But something is missing completely in the list of answers. If you know you have a tight connection and your inbound flight is running late, **tell the cabin crew of the inbound flight.** They will get you off the plane in no time, sometimes when everyone's told to buckle up you are also reseated into a free business seat; and they will tell you how to circumvent security.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to [Mark's answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/106872/12011), a post mentioning the airline may also be helpful. While it's not necessarily the airline's fault, they have more power to put pressure on the airport and/or security contractors to do their jobs efficiently.

Missed connections are expensive and inconvenient not only to the passengers, but also to the airlines. Security causing passengers to unnecessarily miss a flight is something that (good) airline do care about. In addition to the bad PR the airline gets from passengers missing flights, having to re-accommodate passengers on later flights, put them up in hotels, pay for delay expenses or refund tickets, etc. are large costs to the airline. There always going to be a few incidents everywhere, but if it's something that's becoming a common pattern at an airport, an airline (especially a major one that represents a lot of the airport's traffic) can put a lot of pressure on the right people to get things done more efficiently.

If the security contractors aren't concerned enough with helping to keep the airport operations running smoothly, the airline can push to either get the contractor to start caring or replace them with one that does care.